# Ext.Window.show() keeps the old parameter value when re-opens the window

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I have a Ext.Window which is called inside a function. I pass a parameter to `window` through function. When I try to re-open `window` with a new value, `window` performs operations with the old value.

Here is my code -

```
var Win;
LoadWindow = function (id) {
if (!Win) {
    Win = new Ext.Window({
        id: 'Pop-win',
        layout: 'fit',
        width: 650,
        modal: true,
        height: 450,
        closeAction: 'close',
        plain: true,
        items: [Panel],
        listeners: {
            close: function (w) {
               Win.removeAll();
            },
            show: function (p) {
                Store.reload({
                    params: {
                        'ID': id
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
Win.show();
}
```

**PS: I Use extjs 3.4 version**

Comment: `if (!Win)` will prevent the creation of a new window, so `Win` will always be the first window no mather what you pass in `id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the Store.reload(); part out of the show listener. The id it refers to is always referring to the first time you create the window.

If this window is not being used too often, it might suffice to simply change it to use **closeAction: 'destroy'** so that you generate a new window each time. If you need to reuse it, write a helper function on the window that reloads the store separately, and call Win.customStoreReload() followed by Win.show(). By the way, closeAction: 'close' is also not a valid closeAction. The config can only be set to either 'destroy' or 'hide'.

```
LoadWindow = function (id) {
    if (!Win) {
        Win = new Ext.Window({
            id: 'Pop-win',
            layout: 'fit',
            width: 650,
            modal: true,
            height: 450,
            closeAction: 'hide', // either 'hide' or 'destroy'. 'close' is not a valid option
            plain: true,
            items: [Panel],
            listeners: {
                close: function (w) {
                    Win.removeAll();
                }
            }
        });
    }
    Store.reload({params: { 'ID': id }});
    Win.show();
}
```

Comment: suppose, I have a `<a href>` in a .js file from where I call `LoadWindow(id)`. This `id` may be different each time. So I want to open a new window for each `id`. So I cant avoid loading `store` in `show:`

Comment: Have you tried using closeAction: 'destroy'. The problem right now is you are keeping the window in memory and calling the same one each time, so the "id" that's tied to your show listener is never actually renewed (it is only set on construction if that makes sense). It uses the id from your first instantiation. If you are looking to reuse the window, you would need to call a separate function that actually reloads the store manually before each window showing.

Comment: I've added code to explain my answer a bit more. Assuming you are only ever showing the window through the LoadWindow function, I see no reason why moving the Store.reload out of the show would not work. That being said though, I am assuming you have the store tied to the window somewhere else in your code, and that is being handled properly already just by loading the store.